# How does Bitwise AND interact with boolean values?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

I have come across a piece of code that I can't wrap my head around:

```
public void Connect()
{
    if (!(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_vpnConnectionName) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_ipToPing)))
    {
        return;
    }

    GetConnected();
}
```

I've researched the single ampersand on SO and elsewhere, and [found it is a Bitwise AND operand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427585/understanding-the-bitwise-and-operator). However the explanations all revolve around integers.

I can understand the applicability of bitwise operations on integers, but how are they applicable to booleans?

Comment: Try to avoid asking two questions in the same question. Typically only one gets answered

Comment: Look up demorgans law and you'll find that your transformation is correct.

Comment: There is no distinction between *int* and *bool* after the C# compiler is done with it.  The CLR treats them as ints with the expected outcome when you logically-and them.  Also the reason that VB.NET's True is -1, a language that historically did not distinguish between logical and bit-wise AND.  So the answer to Eric's comment "are bools bits" is Yes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a logical operator on bools that evaluates both sides regardless of the value of the left side.

Comment: @Eric I believe it is a bitwise operator, certainly on the IL level. This comes to play with booleans that are not 0 or 1 which are legal on the CLR. Is that true? See http://pastebin.com/U7vqpn6G This would be reproducible using verifiable, safe IL.

Comment: @usr people who store things other than zero or one in a boolean are looking for trouble and should not be surprised when they find it.

Answer (score 3):

For `bool`, [`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx) isn't a bitwise `AND` operator - it's the non-short-circuiting logical `AND` operator - it always evaluates both arguments - as opposed to the "usual" `&&` operator that only evaluates its second argument if its first argument is `true`.

(Realised that it may not be obvious, that the first `&` above is linked to the actual [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c.aspx))

Comment: @PaulyGlott - no, `&&` doesn't evaluate its second argument if the first argument is `false`.

Comment: Also though `&` *behaves* like a **logical** `AND` for booleans, it certainly remains to *be* a **bitwise** `AND` operator. The bools simply are defined as such, that the bitwise operation on their bits behaves like a logical one.