# What does &= mean in objective c?

Tags: objective-c

I ran into this bit of code today:

```
indexValid &= x >= 0;
```

What does the &= mean? Could someone explain what is occurring in this statement?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but i guess, `Bit-wise-AND` and `assignment` too.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427585/understanding-the-bitwise-and-operator

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not about Objective-C, but regular C.

Here the statement with the `&=` operator is equivalent to `indexValid = indexValid & (x >= 0)`.
The `&` operator itself is called the bitwise and operator, and `AND`s the operands. Which means, returns `1` only if both operands are `1`, else returns `0` if any of the operands is not `1`. `AND`ing and `OR`ing is commonly used in setting flags in software.

For example, if `indexValid` is `0011010` in binary and you `AND` it with `(x >= 0)` (which is a boolean expression result, either 1 or 0), the result is `0000000` and (let's say x >= 0 evaluates to 1) as `0011010 & 0000001` evaluates to `0000000`.

If you don't know about binary logic, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic is a good source to start.

Comment: My thought process may be grossly off right now, but shouldn't `0011010 & 0000001` evaluate to `0`?

Comment: It is, but I understood the solution a bit more with Can's answer. Nothing personal :)

Comment: @guy8214: indeed his answer is better :)

Answer (score 2):

It is the `bitwise AND` plus `assignment operator` (or 'and accumulate').

It combines a `bitwise AND` against the left-hand operand with assignment to said operand.

```
x&= y;
```

is

```
x= x & y;
```