# C++ meaning |= and &=

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, box2d, bitwise-operators

I have a part of code that contains the following functions:

```
void Keyboard(int key)
{
    switch (key) {
    case GLFW_KEY_A: m_controlState |= TDC_LEFT; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_D: m_controlState |= TDC_RIGHT; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_W: m_controlState |= TDC_UP; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_S: m_controlState |= TDC_DOWN; break;
    default: Test::Keyboard(key);
    }
}

void KeyboardUp( int key)
{
    switch (key) {
    case GLFW_KEY_A: m_controlState &= ~TDC_LEFT; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_D: m_controlState &= ~TDC_RIGHT; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_W: m_controlState &= ~TDC_UP; break;
    case GLFW_KEY_S: m_controlState &= ~TDC_DOWN; break;
    default: Test::Keyboard(key);
    }
}
```

I know what a switch case is but I don't understand what these parts do.

```
m_controlState |= TDC_LEFT
m_controlState &= ~TDC_LEFT
```

`m_controlState` is an int. The `GFLW_KEY`'s also refer to an int value.

Could someone explain what these parts do? An example with input values and results would be nice.

*Not equal to the linked question because I also ask about &=*

Comment: see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: @twin they only give it a name, not an explenation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Also I think it should be explained what these operators do and are used this way.

m_controlState serves as flags, which means it contains in binary form which of the keys are pressed.
For example if the values of tds constants are chosed like this:

```
TDS_LEFT             = 0x00001
TDS_RIGH = 0x01 << 2 = 0x00010 
TDS_UP   = 0x01 << 3 = 0x00100
TDS_DOWN = 0x01 << 4 = 0x01000
```

Then in single integer you can store information which options are set. To do that you just have to check if bit that corresponds on each setting is 1 or 0.

So to set TDS_LEFT option, you have to OR the current state with 0x00001( which is TDS_LEFT), so in code

```
m_controlState = m_controlState | TDS_LEFT
```

which is the same as

```
m_controlState |= TDS_LEFT.
```

To unset TDS_LEFT option you have to AND it with ~TDS_LEFT. So

```
m_controlState = m_controlState & ~TDS_LEFT
```

which is the same as:

```
m_controlState &= ~TDS_LEFT
```

You can also check: [How to use enums as flags in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448396/how-to-use-enums-as-flags-in-c).
Hope that makes it clearer.

Comment: Add in a small bit about what AND and OR are (the C++ notation), and possibly change "or" and "and" to `or` and `and`. and this is easily the best answer.

Answer (score 7):

`&=`/`|=` operators in a sense are similar to `+=`/`-=` (i.e. `a &= b` is equivalent to `a = a & b`). But, they do binary operations. `&` is doing bitwise and operation, while `|` is doing bitwise or operation.

Example:

a = 1101

b = 1011

a & b = 1001

a | b = 1111

Answer (score 1):

`x |= y` is equivalent to `x = x|y`

In general, for any binary operator `*`, `a *= b` is equivalent to `a = a*b`

If you want to know what `&` and `|` are, read  about [bitwise operators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3427633/4077900).

Answer (score 1):

These are bitwise AND and OR operations. The lines you mentioned are equivalent to:

```
m_controlState = m_controlState | TDC_LEFT;
m_controlState = m_controlState & ~TDC_LEFT
```

Answer (score 1):

These two:

```
m_controlState |= TDC_LEFT
m_controlState &= ~TDC_LEFT
```

are equivalent to:

```
m_controlState = m_controlState | TDC_LEFT
m_controlState = m_controlState & ~TDC_LEFT
```

It works like this with all builtin X= operators.

`m_controlState` is most likely treated as a bitset. `m_controlState` may be, e.g. `01010000` (realistically, it will be larger than 8 bits).

1) `|` is **bitwise or**, which is equivalent to **addition** to that bitset.

So if TDC_LEFT is 00000010:

```
01010000 | 00000010 = 01010010
```

2) `~` is bitwise **negation**:

```
~00000010 = 111111101
```

And if you do 
`01010010 & ~(00000010) = 01010000`, it's effectively equivalent to **bitset difference**.

## In short:

```
bitsetA + bitsetB <=> bitsetA | bitset
bitsetA - bitsetB <=> bitsetA & ~ bitset
```

Answer (score 0):

`x |= y` specifically turns on (sets to 1) those bits in `x` present in `y`, leaving all the others in `x` as they were.

`x &= ~y` specifically turns off (sets to 0) those bits in `x` present in `y`, leaving all the others in `x` as they were.

Answer (score 0):

it's a simple way to set & reset specific bit in a word.

bitword |= MASK is a shorthand of bitword = bitword | MASK which sets the mask bit

bitword &= ~MASK clears that bit (check your boolean algebra notebook to see why)