# Bitwise operation |= in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am going through example code and found this operation:

```
displayMap[x + (y/8)*LCD_WIDTH]|= 1 (shift by) shift;
```

where

```
byte shift = y % 8;
```

I understand `|` operand and `=` but what are two of them together do.

Comment: They do exactly that, bitwise or *and* assignment, all in one go.

Comment: `|=` is shorthand for doing an `OR` operation and assignment. For example,, `x |= 3` is equivalent to `x = x | 3`. You can also use other operators (`+, -, *, &`, etc) in this manner as well.

Comment: The first hit in google answers your question. It's a tutorial so you might even learn some more C basics while you're there.

Comment: [What does “|=” mean? (pipe equal operator)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14295469/995714)

Comment: [C++ meaning |= and &=](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33304407/995714)

Answer (score 14):

`|` performs a bitwise OR on the two operands it is passed.

For example,

```
byte b = 0x0A | 0x50;
```

If you look at the underlying bits for `0x0A` and `0x50`, they are `0b00001010` and `0b01010000` respectively.  When combined with the OR operator the result in `b` is `0b01011010`, or `0x5A` in hexadecimal.

`|=` is analogous to operators like `+=` and `-=` in that it will perform a bitwise OR on the two operands then store the result in the left operator.

```
byte b = 0x0A;
b |= 0x50;

// after this b = 0x5A
```