# Binary AND operator in If statement condition

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, operators

I Didn't understand this piece of code. Any help?

```
    for(j = 0x40; j > 0; j = j >> 1) 
    {
     if(0xC9 & j)
       LED = 1;
     else
       LED = 0;
     delay_us(10);
       CLK = 1;
     delay_us(10);
       CLK = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Well it's binary and operator. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: Fire the intern who indented that code.

Comment: how does it work? What condition is passed in if (condition).?

Comment: The `if`-statement expression has a bitwise and operator. Is it how this works that you wish to find? Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427585/? Or is it how C handles booleans?

Answer (score 2):

The for loop is a bit tricky. This operation :

```
j = j >> 1
```

Is basically an integer division by two. All the bits are shifted from 1 bit to the right. Example :

```
unsigned char foo = 0x20; //   Binary : 0010 0000, Decimal : 32
foo = foo >> 1; //Hex : 0x10,  Binary : 0001 0000, Decimal : 16
```

This if statement :

```
if(0xC9 & j)
```

is testing if some bits are set to 1 in the loop variable. 0xC9 is a number in which bits 7, 6, 3 and 0 are set to 1 (0xC9 = 0b11001001 = 201). If any of these bits equals '1' in j, then the condition is true.

This is not really a user-friendly code, the one who wrote it should use some #define to make it more readable. The algorithm is also unclear, using bitwise operations is not a pretext to writing unreadable code.

Answer (score 1):

The `if`-statement evaluates `0xC9 & j`, and if that comes out as non-zero then it's treated as "true" (`LED = 1`), otherwise it's "false" (`LED = 0`).

In C (and many other languages), non-zero means "true" and zero means "false" when used in a boolean context.