# What does the 'and' instruction do to the operands in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, bitwise-operators, instructions, bitwise-and

What does the 'and' instruction do in assembly language? I was told that it checks the bit order of the operands and sets the 1s to true and anything else to false, but I don't know what it actually does or what effect it has on the code.

Comment: This should be described in the documentation for any assembler that has an `and` instruction. It does a bit-wise Boolean "and" between two operands. In other words, corresponding bits (bit n in each operand) are anded, in the Boolean operation sense, giving bit n of the result. In Boolean logic, 1 and 1 = 1, but 0 and x (anything else) = 0. Thus, `10111010 and 01101011` results in `00101010`. If you're not familiar with Boolean logic, I suggest starting there and look it up since it's the rudimentary basis of how most electronic computers work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding the bitwise AND Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427585/understanding-the-bitwise-and-operator)

Answer (score 6):

AND instruction compares the bits in the 2 operands in the following manner:

```
Bit position 1234 5678
Operand A -- 1101 1001
Operand B -- 1001 0111
             _________
Result ----- 1001 0001
```

The bits at position 1, 4 and 8 are true in both bytes so the position 1,4 and 8 of the resulting byte will be true. The result will be stored in the first operand.

Answer (score 1):

For 32-bit registers, it does 32 separate/independent boolean `and` operations, one for each bit position.  (true if both inputs are true, otherwise false.)

Like `output[4] = a[4] & b[4]`, where this pseudocode syntax is describing the inputs/output as arrays of bits.

It's exactly the same operation as C's bitwise `&` or `&=` operator.

(Not C's `&&` logical-and operator, which checks for `!=0`).

Comment: So it checks if both operands are the same?

Comment: @user548010: no, it intersects two bitmaps.  Bit 3 of the result does not depend on bit 4 of either input.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction `and` performs bit-wise AND operation on its operands. For example the instruction `and al, bl` should compute the AND operation on the register `al` and `bl` (as illustrated by @Serkratos121) and store the result in `al` register.

It can be used to clear bit(s) off a register. A popular example for this is to convert a lowercase character to uppercase. To convert the `m` to `M`. One can write:

```
mov al, 'm' ; this moves the ascii code of m i.e. 109 to al register
```

Now, to convert this uppercase, subtract 32 from `al`. But instead of using `sub al, 32d`, one can write:

```
and al, 11011111b ; this clears the 5th bit (LSB is 0th bit)
```

So, `al` now contains 77 which is the ascii code for `M`.

Comment: If you're counting from zero, you should say "bit #5" to describe the `~(1<<5)` position.  [Ordinal numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_numeral) like first, second, ..., fifth don't enumerate from zeroth).  i.e. bit #5 is the 6th bit.

Answer (score 1):

The `and` instruction performs a bit-wise AND for every bit in a number.

**Bit-Wise AND**

Bit-Wise AND, not to be confused with C’s logical AND, checks each bit position. If it finds that both operando have a 1 bit in the same position, the output bit in the position will be a 1. If it find that both bits are 0 or that 1 bit is 0 and the other is 1 the output bit in that position with be 0.

```
Bit Position — 1234 5678
Operand 1 ———— 0111 0101
Operand 2 ———— 1101 1111
               ————————-
Output ——————- 0101 0101
```

**Functional Example**

The `and` instruction has multiple uses. A common one is the convert lowercase ASCII characters to uppercase ones. This can be done by subtracting `32` but that will also effect uppercase letters.

```
mov dx, ‘a’
and dx, 11011111b
```

The `dx` register will now contain `A`. It works like this:

```
Bit Position - 1234 5678
Operand 1 ———- 0110 0001
Operand 2 ———- 1101 1111
               ————————-
Output ——————- 0100 0001
```

Comment: `sub dx, 32` isn't slower than `and` on any x86 CPUs I'm aware of (https://agner.org/optimize/ / https://uops.info/, and historically https://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~fpf/Uebungen/GdR-SS02/opcode_i.html), or non-x86.  The main reason to use `and` or `or` on chars is that if it was already an upper-case letter, `and` doesn't change it, unlike `sub`.  So isalpha for ASCII can be `and` / `sub dx, 'A'` / `cmp dx, 25` / `ja non_alphabetic` as in [What is the idea behind ^= 32, that converts lowercase letters to upper and vice versa?](//stackoverflow.com/a/54585515)

Comment: Also, `32b` isn't a valid integer constant in assembly; you mean `32` (decimal) or `100000b`.