# questions about local and push notifications on ios

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uilocalnotification

I can't find sure answers on some questions I had about push/local notifications.

1. Does disabling push notifications also disable local notifications?
2. Can I detect if the user has disabled push notifications for my application? If so, how do I do that? EDIT: Just as I submitted the  question, I found: [Determine on iPhone if user has enabled push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535403/determine-on-iphone-if-user-has-enabled-push-notifications) That's the recommended way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Disabling push notifications does not disable local notifications, they are independent of each other.
2. You can check that way, that will indeed work. Another alternative is to set a persistent flag in your AppDelegate class.

   ```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
   {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"registeredForPush"];
   }

   - (void) application: (UIApplication *) application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
   {
       [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:@"registeredForPush"];
   }
   ```

Comment: Pointer 1 of this answer is wrong. Excluding the app from Notification Center does disable local notification. We've tested on actual device.