# How to find wheather the Pushnotification is enabled or not?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to find out if the user already enabled the pus notification,How to do this ?

I have tried with this..

```
  UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
  if (types ==  UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone){

       NSLog(@"Push is off");

    }
```

But its not working and "types" always gives the value "7"

Comment: See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535403/determine-on-iphone-if-user-has-enabled-push-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIRemoteNotificationType` Types :

```
0 - None
1 - Badge,
2 - Sound,
4 - Alert,
5 - Badge & Alert Only,
6 - Alert & Sound Only,
7 - All Badge,Sound,Alert.
8 - NewsstandContentAvailability.
```