# Push Notifications for iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, push

When I implement "Push Notifications" functionality in my application, in the settings of the phone the user can choose if he want to have the push notifications enabled or disabled.

Is it possible that I disable this functionality? My application has push notifications by default disabled and the user can subscribe to various kinds of events to get push through the app.

So this "general", enable/disable functionality is really a pain for the architecture of my app , my databases etc.

Also I support 4 different platforms of mobile devices, that don't have this functionality. So I cant have it only for 1 platform..

Is it possible not to be there?

Comment: Are you wanting to support the notifications but not allow the user to disable them?

Comment: I dont want the user to be able to disable it from the phones' settings menu. He can subscribe unsubscribe through the app.

Comment: This cant be done for that exact reason. To prevent developers from enabling disabling them without users consent.

Comment: in wp7 , bb7 and android this is not the case though. How the hell will i handle this on my database?

Comment: I'm confused when you say handle this on your database? What exactly are you trying to accomplish? iOS usage guidelines give the user the option to prevent notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent the user from disabling/enabling Push Notifications. Apple is pretty clear in regards to actions like this. They do not want a developer to be able to restrict any basic iOS functionality.

You say that your app has push notifications disabled by default. Why are you concerned about this? Also, handling push notifications in an app is actually somewhat easy and does not require much code at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can not do it at app end but you can put a check on server side to send the notification only on those devices on which the applicable users are logged in.
try this it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Apple's Push Notifications you cannot stop the user from disabling display of your notifications.

Answer (score 0):

This should really be more of a minor inconvenience than a big problem.

If user had disabled notifications from outside your app (in device settings) you can simply perform the same actions as if he did it inside your app.

On how to check if notifications for your app are enabled or not check here: [Determine on iPhone if user has enabled push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1535403/653513)

As for not allowing the user to disable notifications within device settings: it's a no-go.