# Enable/disable notifications in settings controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, push-notification

The IOS app that I'm building uses push notifications. Apple requires you to ask the user wether they want this or not, the first time they run the app:

```
if([UIApplication instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil]];
}
```

But, the user could change his/her mind during the use of the application and toggle notifications on or off in a settings controller by use of a UISwitch.

How can I catch the current notifications value and register/unregister the user from the notifications?
This is what I have found on the internet but doesn't seem to work:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] unregisterForRemoteNotifications];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535403/determine-on-iphone-if-user-has-enabled-push-notifications

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to manually unregister the user from notifications if he changes the preferences, but you can check the status any time with this code

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]  respondsToSelector:@selector(isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications)]) {
    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]  isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]){
        NSLog(@"Notifications Enabled iOS 8");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Notifications Not Enabled iOS 8");
    }
} else {
    UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
    if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) {
        NSLog(@"Notifications Enabled iOS 7 or older");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Notifications Not Enabled iOS 7 or older");
    }
}
```