# If I disable push notification on an Android device, will FCM server push a message?

Tags: android, push-notification

If I disable push notification on an Android device, will FCM server push a message? Will this message be sent to device and device won't just show it or the message won't be sent?

Comment: According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28240980) yes the device will receive it. Just it's not gonna be displayed.