# switch off push notifications ios

Tags: ios, notifications

I have a question about push notifications.

I have a database with all tokens devices. This is the structure of the table.

```
ID (number)

APP_NAME (varchar)

APP_TOKEN (varchar)

ENABLE (bool)
```

If the users go to the device settings and switch off my app notifications, there is anyway to change the field enable to false? I mean, I have a plugin in wordpress witch send notifications to all devices registered in my database and I want to know if an user switch off the notifications to put the field "enable" to false and then no send the notification to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check all types of notifications [cf this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28411981/2086502):

```
BOOL remoteNotificationsEnabled, noneEnabled,alertsEnabled, badgesEnabled, soundsEnabled = NO;

// iOS8+
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

     remoteNotificationsEnabled = [UIApplication sharedApplication].isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications;

     UIUserNotificationSettings *userNotificationSettings = [UIApplication sharedApplication].currentUserNotificationSettings;

     noneEnabled = userNotificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone;
     alertsEnabled = userNotificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
     badgesEnabled = userNotificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeBadge;
     soundsEnabled = userNotificationSettings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeSound;
}
else {  // iOS 7 and below
      UIRemoteNotificationType enabledRemoteNotificationTypes = [UIApplication sharedApplication].enabledRemoteNotificationTypes;

      noneEnabled = enabledRemoteNotificationTypes == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone;
      alertsEnabled = enabledRemoteNotificationTypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert;
      badgesEnabled = enabledRemoteNotificationTypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge;
      soundsEnabled = enabledRemoteNotificationTypes & UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
}
```

Then depending of the results, update your boolean on your backend by making a call to your API.

Comment: There is anyway to do for iOS 7 or earlier?

Comment: The problem now is that when the user disables the push notification i can't get the device token so i can't go to my table and update the value "enable"

Comment: You should not identify your users by their device token. Don't you have another way to identify them ? id, email, anything ?

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/6993440/2086502 there is a way to have a unique identifier for a device. Just have a relationship in your database to link a unique id to the device token.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no delegate callback from iOS that inform the app when push notification is enabled or disabled from Settings app. Application need to query the `UIApplication` property `enabledRemoteNotificationTypes` for example in `applicationDidBecomeActive:` and then make a server call to save the setting like in your case `ENABLE = NO`.

However, even if server sends the notification when user choose to not listen to it, iOS ignores the notification.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the enabled notification flags on application launch. Then set your enabled flag accordingly with a server call

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
if (types == UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone) {
     //set your flag to disabled
}
```