# User Opt-In and Opt-Out Statistics parse.com

Tags: android, ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I want to migrate from an exiting custom developed push solution to a third party service.

On a lot of pages I've seen that parse is a very good alternative (Urban Airship too, but that's not in our budget).

The main features what we need are:

- Push Sends vs Open
- Push Active Users based on time, we need to see if users opt out because of our sent push notifications (we need to evaluate when we've sent too many notifications and there are too many push opt-outs)

But I've seen that with parse.com I'm not able to keeping track of active users. Is this correctly or did I not see this feature?

What other solutions you can recommend (we send 3-4 messages/day to 80k users, android and ios).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of your question and Parse, the analytics for active push users is not offered by Parse without a bit of customization. However, you could keep track of whether the user has push notifications enabled on the User or Installation object. Then, you can use those numbers in your analytics software of choice or run a Cloud Code job that runs daily to see what users have push enabled.

E.g., in iOS you could use/modify the solution given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15008579/2428148) to check based on which types of push notifications should be enabled.

For tracking purposes, you can then send this data to the tracking service of your choice.

For data on push opens, Parse offers a methods to [track them](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-tracking-pushes-and-app-opens), e.g. in iOS:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
  if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
    // The application was just brought from the background to the foreground,
    // so we consider the app as having been "opened by a push notification."
    [PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload:userInfo];
  }
}
```

Let me know if you're looking for something else here.