# Detecting Push Notification enabled with UIBackgroundModes configured in Info.plist

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications

this is my question:

I implemented this code for detected is user enabled or not Push Notification

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications]) {
  NSLog(@"Yes, s(he) accepted Push Notification");
} else {
  NSLog(@"No, s(he) rejected Push Notification");
}
```

which, it works very well. But I had to implemented to receive silent Push Notification in background, so I added this code in my `Info.plist`

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

Then, when I added this, the code that detected if user enabled or not `Push notification` always return TRUE, it doesn't matter if user enabled or not Push Notification. There is any way to detect only if the user enabled visible Push Notification (alerts in the top of the phone), allowing the UIBackgroundModes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine on iPhone if user has enabled push notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535403/determine-on-iphone-if-user-has-enabled-push-notifications)

Comment: It was not the same because it refers in general, but into comments is the solution... thanks @dan

Answer (score 0):

Is not [[UIApplication sharedApplication] isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications] correct to use. To know the decision of the user about Push notification is with 
**currentUserNotificationSettings**

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] currentUserNotificationSettings];

if (!notificationSettings || (notificationSettings.types == UIUserNotificationTypeNone)) {
      isEnabled = NO;
} else {
      isEnabled = YES;
}
```