# Check Push if notification permission asked or not

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have already seen [Determine on iPhone if user has enabled push notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535403/determine-on-iphone-if-user-has-enabled-push-notifications/39664778#39664778)

But My Question is some different.  I need to show a "navigate to settings" screen if push notification permission is denied by the user. How can we check if push permission has been asked before or not? `if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {` is working fine and it is able to get all the `status`, but for earlier versions I am not able to figure it out.

I have following code:

```
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: .main) {[weak self] (notificaiont) in
        guard let strongSelf = self  else {return }

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: {settings in

                switch settings.authorizationStatus {
                case .notDetermined:
                    AppDelegate.sharedDelegate.registerForPush()
                case .denied:
                    AppDelegate.sharedDelegate.navigateUesrToSettings(withMessage: "Allow app to send notifications")
                case .authorized:
                    strongSelf.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    break
                }
            })
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            if UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {
                strongSelf.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                //what should i call here  registerForPush for navigate to setting ?
               // AppDelegate.sharedDelegate.registerForPush()
                AppDelegate.sharedDelegate.navigateUesrToSettings(withMessage: "Allow app to send notifications")

            }
        }
    }
```

In  `// Fallback on earlier versions` 's else part I am confused, do I need to call

`AppDelegate.sharedDelegate.registerForPush()`

or

`AppDelegate.sharedDelegate.navigateUesrToSettings(withMessage: "Allow app to send notifications")`

? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have to store this yourself, e.g. in user defaults. When you prompt the user for the permission, set the flag to `true`; something like this:

```
if UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {
  // equivalent to .authorized case
}
else if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "didAskForPushPermission") 
{
  // equivalent to .notDetermined case
  UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "didAskForPushPermission")
}
else {
  // equivalent to .denied case
}
```